# Laravel eloquent upsert does not update?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Why is it laravel does not update existing data, it keeps inserting new rows? Is there something wrong in my code? thanks for reply

I have here below data to be inserted. Insertion works well, but when I ran the seeder again, it does not update existing data containing `field`, but keeps inserting.

---

```
StudentRepresentative::upsert([
            [
                'field' => 'Sales Department',
                'student_name' => 'Juan',
            ],
            [
                'field' => 'It Department',
                'student_name' => 'Regina',
            ],
        ], ['student_name'], ['field']); // 2nd & 3rd argument, either way it's still not updating and keeps inserting
```

Comment: Pass third argument which tells the column names to be updated

Comment: the second argument of the upsert is the uniqueBy, and you are passing [
                'field' => 'It Department',
                'student_name' => 'Regina',
            ] is this what you want? to check if the row contains field and student_name then update

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid nah not working sir. I actually tried that one before posting the quesiton. (i updated the question description though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your issue, and ended up with the following [stackoverflow](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/108622/how-does-upsert-work-when-no-external-id-is-specified). I tried adding the `id` column as it stated below, and the `upsert` worked as expected. I can't explain how it worked though, but I hope the following statement from the following source could help you.

> Upsert is a merging of the words insert and update. This call is available for objects if the object has an external ID field or a field with the idLookup field property.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_upsert.htm

---

Try this one, hope it will work also in your end.

```
StudentRepresentative::upsert([
            [
                'id' => 1,
                'field' => 'Sales Department',
                'student_name' => 'Juan',
            ],
            [
                'id' => 2,
                'field' => 'It Department',
                'student_name' => 'Regina',
            ],
        ], ['id', 'field']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed the second argument in function where at least it define your unique identifier columns to be updated if exists.

```
StudentRepresentative::upsert([
            [
                'field' => 'Sales Department',
                'student_name' => 'Juan',
            ],
            [
                'field' => 'It Department',
                'student_name' => 'Regina',
            ],
        ],['student_name'], ['field']);
```

Comment: nah not working sir. I actually tried that one before posting the quesiton. (i updated the question description though)